# How to convert input by the user (int) to String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have written this code to convert any integer typed in by the user to a day of the week. I have not been able to resolve some errors I have encountered, what am I missing?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
   class dayofweek2 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner daynumber = new Scanner(System.in);

         String input = Integer.parseInt(daynumber);
         System.out.println("Enter a number from 1 to 7");
         if (input == 1 ) {
            System.out.println("monday");
         }
         if (input == 2 ) {
            System.out.println("tuesday");
         }
         if (input == 3 ) {
            System.out.println("wednesday");
         }
         if (input == 4 ) {
            System.out.println("thursday");
         }
         if (input == 5 ) {
            System.out.println("friday");
         }
         if (input == 6 ) {
            System.out.println("saturday");
         }
         if (input == 7 ) {
            System.out.println("sunday");
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: `If(input == 1 );` `if` is lower case and there should not be a semicolon

Comment: daynumber has no number either. You cannot parse that.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` does not take a Scanner Object

Comment: i noticed,i corrected the if to lowercase and still receive errors

Comment: how can i make it work?? if there is a way to make it work

Comment: please edit your question with the fixes that have been suggested.  Its obvious you are not actually running the code listed here.  Also include the exact error message you see.  It is just not practical for someone to guess which of the many errors you have fixed and which ones you haven't yet.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple stray/stale semicolons in your code. I have fixed your code for you :)

TIP: you could use you a `switch` statement to simplify your logic and make it much more readable

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   class dayofweek2 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner daynumber = new Scanner(System.in); // Print to screen, querying user
         System.out.println("Enter a number from 1 to 7");
         String j = daynumber.nextLine(); // Per requirements, obtain String
         Integer input = Integer.parseInt(j); // Convert String to Integer

         if (input == 1 ) { // Begin processing of input
            System.out.println("monday");
         }
         if (input == 2 ) {
            System.out.println("tuesday");
         }
         if (input == 3 ) {
            System.out.println("wednesday");
         }
         if (input == 4 ) {
            System.out.println("thursday");
         }
         if (input == 5 ) {
            System.out.println("friday");
         }
         if (input == 6 ) {
            System.out.println("saturday");
         }
         if (input == 7 ) {
            System.out.println("sunday");
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: i have one written with switch statement but there are a few errors in the code too

Comment: fixed, didn't notice you were using Scanner incorrectly

Comment: First get the input, then tell the user to "Enter a number"?  Also why go through the hassle of converting a String to an Int when Scanner will do it for you

Comment: @ScaryWombat fixed and yes I found it silly as well but maybe his "requirements" or homework sheet wants it that way

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of unfortunate semicolons. They terminate your `if` bodies. Also, I would use `Scanner#nextInt()` and a different variable name for the `Scanner`. Next, display the prompt before you try to read the `input`. And, I would eliminate all of those `if`(s) by using an array. Something like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number from 1 to 7");
int input = scan.nextInt();
String[] days = { "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday",
        "friday", "saturday", "sunday" };
if (input >= 1 && input <= 7) {
    System.out.println(days[input - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Scanner` needs to take some input. You do that by calling `Scanner.nextLine()` or one of the other `next` methods.

In your example, you could do this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine(); // read a line
int daynumber = Integer.parseInt(input); // parse the line that was entered as an integer

switch(daynumber) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much guys,after much hard work I have been able to complete the programand make it run I will post the complete program later for more scrutiny.....Thanks again guys

Answer (score 0):

After

`System.out.println("Enter a number from 1 to 7");`

the logic is to grep the number which user enters and store it in a variable.

Like

`int tmp = daynumber.nextInt();`

and then continue with if or Switch statements